# captions on animation within tabular

Tags: tables, captions, animations

I am trying to make a beamer frame with 4 animations on it. I am currently arranging them in a tabular with 2 col and 2 rows.

```
 \begin{tabular}{cc}

     \animategraphics[...animation arguments ...]{}{}    &
     \animategraphics[...animation arguments ...]{}{}  \\
     \animategraphics[...animation arguments ...]{}{}  &
     \animategraphics[...animation arguments ...]{}{}  

\end{tabular}
```

I would like to add captions, but I do not know how, I tried putting caption before the cell delimiters, and after the cell delimiters. Any advice?

Comment: your text says 2 col and 2 row but the tabular in your code has three rows, one entry in the first, two entries in the second and one in the third. Can you not just put the caption text under each animation so `\ag{}&\ag{}\\cap1&cap2\\ \ag{}&\ag\\cap3&cap4`

Comment: OK I'll make it an answer then:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text says 2 col and 2 row but the tabular in your code has three rows, one entry in the first, two entries in the second and one in the third. Can you not just put the caption text under each animation so

```
 \begin{tabular}{cc}

     \animategraphics[...animation arguments ...]{}{}  & \animategraphics[...animation arguments ...]{}{} \\
caption 1 &  caption 2 \\
     \animategraphics[...animation arguments ...]{}{}  & \animategraphics[...animation arguments ...]{}{}  \\
caption 3 & caption 4

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: I think I fixed the number of rows and columns in my question can you check that I did?

Comment: no it's still wrong it needs to be as I have it (so you could accept my answer:-). Yours has two `\\ ` so that means it has three rows. It has 1 in the first two in the second and one in the third. a 2 by 2 table has `\begin{tabular}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{tabular}` with one `\\ ` and two `&`

Comment: I had my & and my \\ mixed up. Thanks alot David.